# is there a way to change the text displayed on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a way to change the text displayed on hover?

for example, I have a H1 tag and when I hover over it I want the text to change to something else is this possible with HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: It is certainly possible with JavaScript.

Comment: ok thanks, is it possible that you could provide an example of how I would do this?

Comment: Changing the actual value is not possible using CSS only, though youy can use mixed of ::after and content and position that above the h1 to do something around it.

Comment: sorry, I'm unclear on what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, as long as it fits your needs:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
}

h1:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-hover="another text">some text</h1>
```

Comment: It is very nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is the example of how you could achieve this with JavaScript:

```js
function changeText(element) {
  element.innerHTML = "Changed!";
}
```

```html
 <h1 onmouseover="changeText(this)">Hover me!</h1>
```

Eventually, you could add a `onmouseout` to set the text to it's before value.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be achieved in pure CSS using pseudo elements, as for JavaScript, you could do something like this:

```
<h1>Original text</h1>

<script>

    const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');


    h1.onmouseover = function () {
        h1.innerHTML = 'Hover text';
    };

    h1.onmouseout = function () {
        h1.innerHTML = 'Original text';
    };
</script>
```

You might need to use a different selector depending on your page contents, e.g.

```
<h1 class="title">Original text</h1>

const h1 = document.querySelector('h1.title');
```

This could be improved so that the same text isn't hardcoded in the HTML and the JS by using a data attribute.